# onClickListener is not working in Recycler Adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am using Recycler view to show the list but setOnclicklistener is not woking in Recylerview Adapter class . Below is my Adapter class code & xml code.
i m just simply implementing setOnClickListener to adapter same setOnClickListener was working one day ago and

same issue i met with few days ago but i made anothers adapter and it did the trick but again today i met same problem

though i googled but did get the answer and i m posting here question to what could be the reason i meet often where i m making mistake and keep this in mind for further codes.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.chat.Activities.Statedata;
import com.example.chat.Models.StateCases;
import com.example.chat.R;
import com.example.chat.databinding.StateDataItemBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StatelistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StatelistAdapter.StatelistHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<StateCases> stateCases;

    public StatelistAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<StateCases> stateCases) {
        this.context = context;
        this.stateCases = stateCases;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StatelistHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.state_data_item, parent, false);
        return new StatelistHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StatelistHolder holder, int position) {

        StateCases scase = stateCases.get(position);
        holder.binding.states.setText(scase.getStatename());
        holder.binding.sconfirmed.setText(scase.getTodaycases());
        holder.binding.stotay.setText(scase.getTotalcases());
        holder.binding.todayreovered.setText(scase.getTodayrecovered());
        holder.binding.srecovered.setText(scase.getRecovered());
        holder.binding.sdeaths.setText(scase.getDeaths());
        holder.binding.todaydeath.setText(scase.getTodaydeaths());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Statedata.class);
                intent.putExtra("totalcase", scase.getTotalcases());
                intent.putExtra("todaycase", scase.getTodaycases());
                intent.putExtra("statename", scase.getStatename());
                intent.putExtra("todayrecovered", scase.getTodayrecovered());
                intent.putExtra("totalrecovered", scase.getRecovered());
                intent.putExtra("todaydeaths", scase.getTodaydeaths());
                intent.putExtra("totaldeaths", scase.getDeaths());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stateCases.size();
    }

    public class StatelistHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        StateDataItemBinding binding;

        public StatelistHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = StateDataItemBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5"
    tools:context=".Activities.Statewiselist">

    <com.romainpiel.shimmer.ShimmerTextView
        android:id="@+id/lastime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Loading..." />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lastime"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#318797"
                android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView25"
                        android:layout_width="82dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="States"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Total"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView26"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Today Cases"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Latest Reco."
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView28"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Recovered"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Latest deat."
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView29"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:text="Deaths"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/strecyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:shimmer_demo_angle="20"
                app:shimmer_demo_child_count="10"
                app:shimmer_demo_grid_child_count="2"
                app:shimmer_demo_layout="@layout/statelistitem"
                app:shimmer_demo_layout_manager_type="linear_vertical"
                tools:listitem="@layout/state_data_item">

            </com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the reason may be in `StateDataItemBinding`.
Is your `root view` in `state_data_item.xml` is clickable?

Comment: or child view can be clickable?

Comment: Test if any `child view`.setOnClickListener() work.